# Evaluating sinx using Horner's rule with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, trigonometry, taylor-series

Since I have learnt [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) recently. I decided to evaluate sinx using the same with the help of **taylor series**. I wrote some code,  but its showing some great deviation from the original result.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

double sin(double x, int n)
{
    static double s = x;
    if(n==1)
    {
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        s *= 1-((x*x)/((2*n-1)*(2*n-2)));
    }
    return sin(x,n-1);
}

int main()
{
    double r = sin(1,15);
    cout << r;
    return 0;
}
```

> where n are the number of terms of the taylor series

So, passing the parameters as the one mentioned above, the expected result should be **0.841** but when my program is calculating, it shows **0.735**. I also tried giving *n* as a very large number, but it is showing greater deviation than before. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanking you in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure about the formula but the way you have written your function it can only work the first time you call it. Because `s` is only initialised once (on the first call). Every other call after that is going to give a wrong result, even if the formula is correct.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to mix shared mutable state, like static variables, with recursion.

Comment: Recursion is unnecessary here, using a loop would eliminate the need for the static variable

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your "Horner transformation" is correct?

Comment: @molbdnilo and OP - I'm pretty sure it isn't. Just checked with Wolfram Mathematica and got 0.723046.

Comment: @john I have multiplied the result with s and then when finally n reaches the value 1, I simply returned it.

Comment: @molbdnilo I will keep that in mind 

Comment: Thanks Alan, I will keep that in mind 

Comment: @VaibhavSharma [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/b36r4h)'s the same algorithm without recursion (if I read it correctly). It has the same error but it's easier to read.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yup it's the correct one. But the main underlying principle that I am looking in this program is recursion which is not present in your example. Ignoring this, everything's good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment by @Ted Lyngmo, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aWPb8s) is a working version, with minor modifications.

In your original code you can do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bPrs9f):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double sin(double x, int n, double s = 1)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return s*x;
    }
    else
    {
        s = 1 - s*((x*x)/((2*n-1)*(2*n-2)));
    }
    return sin(x, n-1, s);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "std::sin(0.5) = " << std::sin(0.5) << std::endl; 
    double r = sin(0.5, 15);
    cout << r;
    return 0;
}
```

I also suggest you check your formula with `x != 1` since it's harder to miss multiplicative `x` factors that way.